# Updating GAE SDK to 1.7.6

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a little project created and working in GAE SDK 1.7.5, now I'd like to update to version 1.7.6, but I've read several posts reporting problems after the update, such as data lost and so on... so my question is: is it really safe to update? And is it worth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.7.6 is what is running in production.  The only data you could lose is local test data.  If you run the old_dev_appserver.py included in 1.7.6 then you are running the same server as 1.7.5 and you wouldn't normally loose that test data unless you clear the dev datastore.  I can only speak from a python point of view.

Answer (score 1):

When I Upgraded from 1.7.5 to 1.7.6 (in GAE Java version) I lost all local test data.